# How can I pull a value from a JSON object from within another array?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, parsing

My question title may not be the accurate way to describe this issue but it is the best I could come up with. I will make this very easy -- I am trying to get the value of `VALUEIWANT` from the below JSON object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying various methods on w3 schools for 2 hours now.

The closest I have gotten by hard coding was below:

```js
const x =
  { "UserAttributes": 
    [ { "Name" : "sub"
      , "Value": "54f5cdfb-6ec7-4683-fdasfasdf-2324234234"
      } 
    , { "Name" : "custom:var"
      , "Value": "VALUEIWANT"
      } 
    , { "Name" : "email"
      , "Value": "test.user@email.com"
      } 
    ] 
  , "Username": "testuser"
  } 

const y = x.UserAttributes[1].Value
    // y here would result in VALUEIWANT
```

The problem with this is I am not sure that the variable will always be at index 1.

**EDIT For Clarity** My goal is to be able to retrieve this value of "VALUEIWANT" in my console. I need to be able to access the value by using the paired Name of "custom:var". I am unsure if this is possible.

Comment: I want to return the value of "VALUEIWANT" in the console. So the actual value itself.

Comment: Do you want to identify the "Value" you want by the associated "Name"? Or...?

Comment: Lets say the value is not VALUEIWANT, how would you identify which element of the UserAttributes array to pick?  *Is it the one with name==="custom:var"?*

Comment: I think he is referring to dynamically find it as there are going to be more entries within the index.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation -- I have updated my post for clarity.

Comment: A small thing - it's nitpicking essentially, but it's good to know for the future - what you have above is a _Javascript Object_. If you wrote (or _serialized_) that data structure as a **string** using that same _notation_ to indicate keys and values, ***that*** would be _Javascript Object Notation (JSON)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem with this is I am not sure that the variable will always
> be at index 1.

You need to find the index using `findIndex` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex))

```js
const x = {
  "UserAttributes": [{
    "Name": "sub",
    "Value": "54f5cdfb-6ec7-4683-fdasfasdf-2324234234"
  }, {
    "Name": "email",
    "Value": "test.user@email.com"
  }, {
    "Name": "custom:var",
    "Value": "VALUEIWANT"
  }],
  "Username": "testuser"
}
const index = x.UserAttributes.findIndex(item => item.Name === "custom:var");

const y = x.UserAttributes[index].Value;

console.log(y);
```

An helper function for this would be like below

```js
const x = {
  "UserAttributes": [{
    "Name": "sub",
    "Value": "54f5cdfb-6ec7-4683-fdasfasdf-2324234234"
  }, {
    "Name": "custom:var",
    "Value": "VALUEIWANT"
  }, {
    "Name": "email",
    "Value": "test.user@email.com"
  }],
  "Username": "testuser"
}

function getValue(x, name) {
  const index = x.UserAttributes.findIndex(item => item.Name === name);
  return index === -1 ? null : x.UserAttributes[index].Value;
}

// get email
console.log(getValue(x, 'email'));

// get custom:var
console.log(getValue(x, 'custom:var'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on the x.UserAttributes array to search for the item with name of "custom:var", and take the value:

```
const valueYouWant = x.UserAttributes.find(ua => ua.Name === "custom:var").Value;
```